# How to build a Java regular expression pattern using variables

Tags: java, regex

Editing to help clarify request:

I need to build a Java regular expression pattern consisting of three elements; a Regex string concatenated with an integer variable concatenated with the end of the Regex string.

Example HTML:

```
<div class="page">1</div>
<div class="listItem"><a href="this-is/a-dummy-url-extension">
```

Regex pattern I developed:

```
int page = 1; 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("page\">" + page + "</div><div class=\"listItem\"><a href=\"(.*?)\">");
```

Objective: is to use the regex pattern to locate the above HTML line after its been read in line by line using the below methodologies.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/examples/MatcherDemo.java
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html

Right now its not working.

Comment: Have you considered using a DOM parser to do this task in a reliable fashion? See: http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

Comment: "*I think my pattern is off because the string literal version is outputting downstream.*" > Can you give an example of what you mean? How are you printing the value and what do you see?

Comment: Fair enough. Perhaps mention the details of the article for further credit :-)

Comment: I'm still not clear what exact problem you are encountering. Can you create a small, [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem and add it to your question? Something we can copy/paste/run and see the same hanging occur?

Comment: clarified the request above

Answer (score 0):

you can do this :

```
String patternFormat = "slider\">%d</div><div class=\"listItem\"><a href=\"(.*?)\">";
pattern = Pattern.compile(String.format(patternFormat, 1));
pattern = Pattern.compile(String.format(patternFormat, 2));
```

Comment: Why is this solution going to work if the OP's code doesn't? The only thing you seem to have changed is to concatenate the string in a more elegant fashion. Does this address the main problem: "*I think my pattern is off because the string literal version is outputting downstream*"?

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback.  I made my example overly simplified so as to get to the heart of the issue. The fact is that I have well over several hundred pages to get through so I was hoping to increment a variable each time the loop grabs all the data attributes and triggers the loop to move onto iteration 2, 3,...465 etc.  I want to increment the variable + a value to match the loop increment.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @PadawanDeveloper and what is the problem now?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by my lonesome; the issue I ran into was that;

1. I wasn't accounting for white space between the close and opening tags.
2. The the first div tag is on a separate 'line' than the second. Building a pattern that spans two lines doesn't work if you are reading in one line at a time and checking for a pattern in each line . :)

Comment: This is a classic example of the "two problems" problem. When @Duncan suggested using a different approach (DOM/SAX parser) he wasn't being a smart ass. What happens when the layout of the page changes, or another class is added to the div? Your regex will start failing. Regular Expressions are designed to be used with regular languages, but HTML (and other types of SGML) are by definition always context-free languages.

Comment: Thanks Mikkel.  I accidentally deleted my response to Duncan when editing this post.  I had replied stating I couldn't use the DOM parser as we are being asked to use Regex for the assignment.  Otherwise I would have used DOM.

Comment: Oh, ok. But for extra credit maybe you can point out that using a regular expression to parse non-regular languages is a bad idea. :) http://twoproblems.com/1

Comment: @Mikkel - thanks, I plan to return to the DOM parser approach once I graduate.  Two more assignments to go woot wooot!